# What exactly is different between getStaticProps + fallback:true and getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I read [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-pages) many times, but I still have no idea what's the difference between `getStaticProps` using `fallback:tru`e and `getServerSideProps`.

As far as I understand :

**getStaticProps**

`getStaticProps` is rendered at the build time and serves any requests as static HTML files. It is using with pages that are not updated often, for example, an About us page.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

return {
    paths: [{ params: { id: '1' } }, { params: { id: '2' } }]
  }
}
```

But if we put `fallback:true` at the return of the function, and there is a request to the page that is not generated at the build time, Next.js will generate the page as a static page then other requests on this page will be served as a static.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

return {
    paths: [{ params: { id: '1' } }, { params: { id: '2' } }],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

So, `getStaticProps's` concept is working great for me. I think it can work for most scenarios. But if `getStaticProps` is working great, then why do we need `getServerSideProps`?

I understand that Next.js will pre-render each request if we use `getServerSideProps`. But why do we need it, when we can use `getStaticProps` to get the newest data, which I think it is better for TTPB?

Can you guys please explain it to me or guide me to something that can help me totally understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a web crawler that does not run Javascript, when it visits a page that was not built at build time, and its `fallback` is set to be `true`, `Next.js` will serve a fallback version of the page that you defined ([Fallback pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-pages)). The crawler may see something like `<div>Loading</div>`.

Meanwhile, if the crawler visits a page with `getServerSideProps`, `Next.js` will always respond with a page with all the data ready, so the crawler will always get the completed version of the page.

From a user standpoint, the difference is not significant. In fact, the page with `getStaticProps` and `fallback: true` may even result in a better perceived performance.

Also, as more and more crawlers execute JavaScript before indexing JavaScript, I would expect there will be fewer reasons to use `getServerSideProps` in the future.

Comment: Your answer is very clear! So it seem like not much different (if server is working fast in case of use `getServerSideProps` ) from user's point of view. The different is how the crawler see the page.

Comment: On average, serving a static page with fallback should be faster than calling `getServerSideProps` every time. From a cost-effectiveness standpoint, if you host your `Next.js` project on Vercel, it turns your page with `getServerSideProps` into a serverless function, and every invocation costs a tiny bit. If the data on the page will unlikely change (e.g. blog post), it makes sense to serve as a static page.

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation has saved me two days of deployment on Heroku and Vercel, because my page was using `getStaticProps` from the pages\api folder. So I figured since the data is not ready during build time I used `getServerSideProps` instead and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`fallback:true` is set inside getStaticPaths which is used with getStaticProps to pregenerate the dynamic pages.

getStaticPath fethces the database to determine how many pages have to be pregenerated and what would be the dynamic part which is usually "slug" for blogs and "id" for products. Imagine, your page has 1000s of products, and pre-generating each page will take long time. If user just manually types the url "yourDomain/products/100". If that page is not ready, you will be returning a Fallback component.

However getServerSideProps get executed upon request hits the route. with getStaticPaths and getStaticProps(if you are revalidating you have access to request), you have no access to `request` object. for example you might need to extract the cookie and make an api call with this cookie.

Otherwise imagine you have dynamic page "users/[id]", and you are showing users secret data here upon authentication. If you pregenerate this pages, then all other users can see each page.